# DoCmd.TransferText Rounds Text to Integer

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've been using Access vba's `DoCmd.TransferText` command to convert a table of mine to a `.csv` file, and it's worked rather well, but I've realized I'm coming across an issue with the export.

I have an `hours` field that stores text, however, when the table is exported, any text like `1.5` or `3.75` are rounded up to `2` and `4`.

I think I know why this is the case - I am using a specification that changes the Text Qualifier to `{none}`.

It appears that when the quotations are removed, any value that looks like a number is automatically rounded up or down to the nearest integer (I've already tried changing `hours` to a Number with type `Double` and that didn't do the trick).

I need to have the quotations removed, so is there a way to get these hour values with up to two decimal places to stay as they are?

Here's what the command looks like:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "TimecardExportSpecification", 
"TimecardExport", "\timecards\" & timecardName & ".csv", False
```

Comment: Are the numbers rounded when you view the CSV file in a plain text editor, such as Windows Notepad?

Comment: It was a different issue, but the solution suggested by June7 worked out because the custom function prevents the default rounding and text specifications at the same time. @LeeMac The numbers were rounded by the export, so no matter what viewer I used they were rounded (Notepad ++ confirmed this).